# Is there any Default json converters while using Retrofit 1.9.0?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

My question is, is there any default converter, while using `Retrofit 1.9` my json response would be like this:

`{"Result":"1","UserID":"0"}`

Please suggest me how to `parse` this `json` into string?

This is my Main activity:

package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.okhttp.Interceptor;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;

import java.io.IOException;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Response;
import retrofit.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public EditText password,userName;
    Button login,resister;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    TextView tv;
    String TAG="Fails";
    String url="http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc";
    private ModelLogin Result;



    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmployeeCode);

        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);
        userName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorfoucs);


        //progess_msz.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ConnectivityManager cn=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true )
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,"No Network","Please Check Your Network Connectivity",true);
        }

        final   ConnectionDetector    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final String s1 = userName.getText().toString();
                String s2 = password.getText().toString();
                if (s1.equals("")) {
                    userName.setError("Enter Employee Code");
                }
                if (s2.equals("")) {
                    password.setError("Enter Password");

                }
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request original = chain.request();

                        // Customize the request
                        Request request = original.newBuilder()
                                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                .header("Authorization", "auth-token")
                                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                                .build();

                        com.squareup.okhttp.Response response = chain.proceed(request);

                        // Customize or return the response
                        return response;
                    }
                });
                Retrofit retro = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
                RetrofitRest retrofitRest = retro.create(RetrofitRest.class);
                retrofitRest.getResult(s1, s2, new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                        ModelLogin model=new ModelLogin();
                        if(model.getResult().equals("2"))
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome" +""+s1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                    }
                });


                        // public void onResponse(ModelLogin modelLogin, Retrofit retrofit)
                        // {


                        // }

                        // @Override
                        // public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                        //   progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //    ModelLogin modelLogin1=new ModelLogin();
                        //    modelLogin1.getLoginResult();
                        //   LoginResult loginResult=new LoginResult();
                        ///   loginResult.getResult();
                        //   ModelLogin modelLogin=new ModelLogin();
                        // modelLogin.getLoginResult().getResult();
                        //   if()
                        //   {

                        //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"God",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //  }
                        // else {
                        //      Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                        //       startActivity(intent);
                        //  }
                        //  }
//
                        //  @Override
                        //   public void onResponse(Response<LoginResult> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                        //   }

                        ////   @Override
                        //   public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"God",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //   }
                    }
                    //  call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
                    //     @Override
                    //     public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit) {


                    //        }


                    //    @Override
                    //    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    //       Log.d(TAG,"Error");
                    //   }
                    //});





        });

    }


    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon


        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this application?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int d) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

This is my interface:

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 23-11-2015.
 */
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.http.POST;
import retrofit.http.Path;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 03-11-2015.
 */
public interface RetrofitRest {

    @POST("SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login/{EMPLOYEECODE}/{PASSWORD}")
void getResult(@Path("EMPLOYEECODE") String empcode, @Path("PASSWORD") String passwrd, Callback<ModelLogin> callback);



    // @GET("SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/Msg")
    // Call<ModelLogin>verify(@Body ModelLogin result);
}
```

This is my pojo:

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 23-11-2015.
 */
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 13-11-2015.
 */
public  class ModelLogin
{

    @SerializedName("Result")

    private String Result;
    @SerializedName("UserID")
    @Expose
    private Integer UserID;
    @SerializedName("ModuleID")
    @Expose
    private Integer ModuleID;
    @SerializedName("ModuleName")
    @Expose
    private String ModuleName;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The Result
     */
    public String getResult() {
        return Result;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Result
     * The Result
     */
    public void setResult(String Result) {
        this.Result = Result;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The UserID
     */
    public Integer getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param UserID
     * The UserID
     */
    public void setUserID(Integer UserID) {
        this.UserID = UserID;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The ModuleID
     */
    public Integer getModuleID() {
        return ModuleID;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param ModuleID
     * The ModuleID
     */
    public void setModuleID(Integer ModuleID) {
        this.ModuleID = ModuleID;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The ModuleName
     */
    public String getModuleName() {
        return ModuleName;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param ModuleName
     * The ModuleName
     */
    public void setModuleName(String ModuleName) {
        this.ModuleName = ModuleName;
    }

}
```

My error message:

Am trying to make login page using stable retrofit 1.9 but when i tried to run that it throws method error so far what i tried is

This is my main activity:

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Response;
import retrofit.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public EditText password,userName;
    Button login,resister;
    ProgressBar progressbar;
    TextView tv;
    String TAG="Fails";
    String url="http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc";
    private ModelLogin Result;



    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmployeeCode);

        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);
        userName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorfoucs);


        //progess_msz.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ConnectivityManager cn=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true )
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,"No Network","Please Check Your Network Connectivity",true);
        }

        final   ConnectionDetector    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final String s1 = userName.getText().toString();
                String s2 = password.getText().toString();
                if (s1.equals("")) {
                    userName.setError("Enter Employee Code");
                }
                if (s2.equals("")) {
                    password.setError("Enter Password");

                }

                Retrofit retro = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
                RetrofitRest retrofitRest = retro.create(RetrofitRest.class);
                retrofitRest.getResult(s1, s2, new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                        if(response.isSuccess()){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome" +""+s1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                    }
                });


                        // public void onResponse(ModelLogin modelLogin, Retrofit retrofit)
                        // {


                        // }

                        // @Override
                        // public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                        //   progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //    ModelLogin modelLogin1=new ModelLogin();
                        //    modelLogin1.getLoginResult();
                        //   LoginResult loginResult=new LoginResult();
                        ///   loginResult.getResult();
                        //   ModelLogin modelLogin=new ModelLogin();
                        // modelLogin.getLoginResult().getResult();
                        //   if()
                        //   {

                        //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"God",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //  }
                        // else {
                        //      Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                        //       startActivity(intent);
                        //  }
                        //  }
//
                        //  @Override
                        //   public void onResponse(Response<LoginResult> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                        //   }

                        ////   @Override
                        //   public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"God",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //   }
                    }
                    //  call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
                    //     @Override
                    //     public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit) {


                    //        }


                    //    @Override
                    //    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    //       Log.d(TAG,"Error");
                    //   }
                    //});





        });

    }


    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon


        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this application?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int d) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

and this is my pojo:

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 23-11-2015.
 */
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 13-11-2015.
 */
public  class ModelLogin
{

    @SerializedName("Result")

    private String Result;
    @SerializedName("UserID")
    @Expose
    private Integer UserID;
    @SerializedName("ModuleID")
    @Expose
    private Integer ModuleID;
    @SerializedName("ModuleName")
    @Expose
    private String ModuleName;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The Result
     */
    public String getResult() {
        return Result;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Result
     * The Result
     */
    public void setResult(String Result) {
        this.Result = Result;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The UserID
     */
    public Integer getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param UserID
     * The UserID
     */
    public void setUserID(Integer UserID) {
        this.UserID = UserID;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The ModuleID
     */
    public Integer getModuleID() {
        return ModuleID;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param ModuleID
     * The ModuleID
     */
    public void setModuleID(Integer ModuleID) {
        this.ModuleID = ModuleID;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The ModuleName
     */
    public String getModuleName() {
        return ModuleName;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param ModuleName
     * The ModuleName
     */
    public void setModuleName(String ModuleName) {
        this.ModuleName = ModuleName;
    }

}
```

and this is mine build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "first.service.precision.servicefirst"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
        compile 'org.parceler:parceler:0.2.13'
        compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    }
}
```

And my logcat error msg:

```
2-08 10:27:58.602  11156-11156/first.service.precision.servicefirst E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class first.service.precision.servicefirst.ModelLogin
    for method RetrofitRest.getResult
            at retrofit.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:177)
            at retrofit.MethodHandler.createCallAdapter(MethodHandler.java:47)
            at retrofit.MethodHandler.create(MethodHandler.java:26)
            at retrofit.Retrofit.loadMethodHandler(Retrofit.java:151)
            at retrofit.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:132)
            at $Proxy0.getResult(Native Method)
            at first.service.precision.servicefirst.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:76)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4275)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17434)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for class first.service.precision.servicefirst.ModelLogin. Tried:
    * retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
            at retrofit.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:207)
            at retrofit.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:175)
            at retrofit.MethodHandler.createCallAdapter(MethodHandler.java:45)
            ... 16 more
```

This is my Grade:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "first.service.precision.servicefirst"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug{
                debuggable true
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

        }

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
            compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
            compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'
            compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
            compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
            compile 'org.parceler:parceler:0.2.13'
            compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
        }

}
```

Comment: it kind of login activity if Result reponse is 1 it will redirect to next activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll have to create a Bean object for your response. E.g

```
 public class LoginResponse {
   public String Result;
   public String UserId
 }
```

and let the Retrofit rest interface/descriptor for that endpoint return `LoginResponse`. An instance of this object will be returned as part of `CallBack` (`Callback<LoginResponse>`). When `success` is invoked, check the value for `Result` and act accordingly

Comment: ya i did the same thing but its getting service cannot be void

Comment: There is a lot of confusion in the code you posted. Once if you are using retrofit 1.9, you should be using `RestAdapter.Builder` and not `Retrofit.Builder`. Second Retrofit 1.9 doesn't need  Gson as external dependency (get rid of `com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2`). Third you posted two versions of the RestInterace

Comment: sorry i have removed one interface ok i'l remove gson converter

Comment: after i remove that gson from dependency retrofit couldnt be resolved

Comment: are you getting a compile time error ? Are you still using `Retrofit.Builder` ?

Comment: RetrofitRest.Builder is abstract cannot be instantiated

Comment: let's take a step back. get rid of  `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'` and `  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'` from your gradle and add `compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2') {
        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp peer-dependency module and define your own module import
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'`

Comment: I have tried and successfully implemented using beta version but it is not advisable as it is still in beta so i have decided to move for previous stable version

Comment: Then you have to change your code to use Retrofit 1.9 and not having hybrid solutions with stuff from both versions

Comment: 12-08 15:28:50.300  20252-20252/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 278: Landroid/os/Process;.myUserHandle ()Landroid/os/UserHandle;  does this thing is a bug made by me or masters bug anyway i did it thanks @Blackbelt saved my day thank you so much